# QT raise segmentation fault (core dumped) when QApplication exit

Tags: python, c++, c, qt, segmentation-fault

## Description

I'm using Python & QT to do some experiment.
I use Python to create a GUI application by calling QT's functions.
But, when I close a simple GUI application, it raised a **segmentation fault (core dumped)**.

## Sample code

#### C++:

```
// This is python C++ extension
#ifndef QT_API
#define QT_API

#include "Python.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>

#endif

static QSharedPointer<QApplication> pglobal_app;

// api: init
static PyObject* init_wrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    int argc = 1;
    char *argv[] = {""};
    pglobal_app = QSharedPointer<QApplication>(new QApplication(argc, argv));
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

// api: launch
static PyObject* launch_wrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    QPushButton button("Exit");
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, &QApplication::quit);
    button.show();
    pglobal_app->exec();
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

// methods table
static PyMethodDef qt_api_methods[] = {
    { "init", init_wrapper, METH_VARARGS, "init qt_api"},
    { "launch", launch_wrapper, METH_VARARGS, "launch qt_api"},
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

// init qt_api module
PyMODINIT_FUNC initqt_api(void)
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("qt_api", qt_api_methods);
}
```

#### Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os
sys.path.append("build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7")
import qt_api

qt_api.init()
qt_api.launch()
print "BYE"
```

#### Symptoms

When I click the 'Exit' button, the program printed BYE and then raise a segmentation fault.

#### GDB glance

I use GDB to check what's going on. Below is the output.

```
#0  0x00007fd9872ed869 in QWindow::destroy() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#1  0x00007fd988b8e1ad in QWidgetPrivate::deleteTLSysExtra() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#2  0x00007fd988b6278d in QWidgetPrivate::deleteExtra() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#3  0x00007fd988b68cf8 in QWidgetPrivate::~QWidgetPrivate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#4  0x00007fd988b68f39 in QWidgetPrivate::~QWidgetPrivate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#5  0x00007fd9894be666 in QObject::~QObject() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007fd988b71c7a in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#7  0x00007fd988ea5e0e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#8  0x00007fd988b8d48d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#9  0x00007fd9894be666 in QObject::~QObject() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007fd988b71c7a in QWidget::~QWidget() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#11 0x00007fd988b8c299 in QDesktopWidget::~QDesktopWidget() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#12 0x00007fd988b38a5c in QApplication::~QApplication() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#13 0x00007fd988b38e69 in QApplication::~QApplication() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#14 0x00007fd9898cf77e in destroy (this=0x233d220)
    at /home/charles/tools/Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:151
#15 deref (d=0x233d220) at /home/charles/tools/Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:469
#16 deref (this=<optimized out>) at /home/charles/tools/Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:464
#17 QSharedPointer<QApplication>::~QSharedPointer (this=<optimized out>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /home/charles/tools/Qt5.4.0/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qsharedpointer_impl.h:305
#18 0x00007fd98ab15259 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0x7fd98ae986c8 <__exit_funcs>, 
    run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true) at exit.c:82
#19 0x00007fd98ab152a5 in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:104
```

#### Question

1. Why this happening and how to avoid this issue?
2. If I want to invoke `QApplication::quit()` from Python in another thread, what should I do?

Thank you so much.

Comment: But the QApplication::exec() is something like an infinite loop, so `launch_wrapper`(the main thread) won't return untill I click the exit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at your `launch_wrapper`:

```
// api: launch
static PyObject* launch_wrapper(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    QPushButton button("Exit");
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, &QApplication::quit);
    button.show();
    pglobal_app->exec();
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Here you create a `QPushButton`, connect it, show it, and enter the main Qt event loop. 
But you create it on the stack, so when you click that button, the main event loop returns, your `launch_wrapper` returns, and the `QPushButton` is destroyed on the way out.

Now your `pglobal_app` is static, so it's destroyed after all used code has returned, so long after your `QPushButton` is gone.

But internally Qt keeps a hierarchy of parents and childs for pretty much all of its objects, and the parent owns the childs. So when the QApplication is destroyed, it also destroys all of its childs, including your `QPushButton`.

So you have an object being destroyed twice. That's a double-free and undefined behavior. Hence the crash.

To fix this, create all your GUI elements on the heap (i.e. `QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Exit");` and let Qt clean it up with the parent/child hierarchy.

Comment: I'm not familiar with QT's internal behavior. I create `QPushButton button("Exit");` on stack just because it might lead to memory leak when the codes become more and more complex. So, you suggest me creating all GUI elements on heap and QT will manage them automatically, right?

Comment: Basically, yes. You can read more about it here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html

Comment: I've tested the fix, but I still got segmentation fault.

Comment: Try to make your QApplication a normal pointer, not a QSharedPointer. Using a Qt object to manage a QApplication might not be the best idea.

Comment: QApplication is responsible for setting up a *lot* of Qt invariants, many Qt objects depend on it being alive, and QSharedPointer is a Qt object. If that's not it, then I'm afraid your code has yet another problem I'm not seeing.

Comment: According to the QObject doc, I found the QObject will only be automatically destruct if it has parent(ie. parent != 0). So, the fix will lead to a mem-leak when `launch_wrapper` return(I've tested). And the best way to deal with it is to delete it by my self.

Comment: BTW, I found I must delete all the heap variables in this order `delete button; delete pglobal_app;`. If it is reversed, then segmentation fault again. I'm wondering if the button is using something QApplication's stuffs when deleting.